# How can I filter expressions like ".*_" which contain underscore in R?

Tags: r, regex

Trying to filter phrases in a vector `c("phrase\_", "char phrase_char")` results only in `"phrase\_"`.

I tried it e.g. with `grep` and `startsWith` the `"char phrase_char"`) wasn't found.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about vector elements containing specific characters you can use grep().

Example:

```
test <- c("phrase_", "char phrase_char", "char char2 phrase_","only char char2")
grep("*phrase_*",test)
# [1] 1 2 3
grepl("*phrase_*",test)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
test[grep("*phrase_*",test)]
# [1] "phrase_"            "char phrase_char"   "char char2 phrase_"
```